# Is the word English always capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

I correct student mistakes when providing grammar content to them. I frequently encounter the word "English" in e-mail situations and it is not capitalized. I just need some clarification. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you, when you looked up the word "English"?

Comment: I ask these questions as I am assisting numerous English language learners online. I use dictionaries but the explanations in dictionaries can be difficult in some cases.

Comment: I'm someone who enjoys learning from other people. So, I hope to help speakers of other languages to learn and love the idiosyncrasies of English, there are so many!

Idiosyncrasies is the word that I was looking for! @Mari-Lou

Comment: You didn't answer my question or say which dictionaries you consulted in the comments. We don't need to know *why* you posted the question but what makes you think that English is not written with a capital E. You shouldn't be influenced by how ESL learners write the word, after all they're students,  it's to be expected that they get some things wrong.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I appreciate your feedback. I am satisfied with the answer that I received for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it always is, except sometimes when it is used (chiefly in American English) to mean putting a kind of spin on a ball in games like pool.

I think one of the reasons you see it without a capital is that in some languages (certainly French) national names are capitalised when they are nouns (*l'Anglais* = "the English person") but not when they are adjectives (*un livre anglais* = "an English book")

Alternatively, it might just be that people don't think it important in the contexts where you've seen it.